# Selecting one particular camera, locks resolution to 1080p, Unable to change it

Tags: rendering, camera, scene, resolution

*So I've created a scene using multiple cameras.
I've created linked copies of the scenes to render the multiple cameras, however there is this one camera, say Cam03 which when I set as active the resolution changes to 1080p and doesn't change to any other resolution I try. If I try setting 2560x1440, I can type the numbers in or drag the resolution slider, but when I commit the resolution, it changes back to 1920X1080.
Please note the issue is not that I cant set it to 2k or 4k, I know I can just render at a higher percentage if need be, the issue is that the resolution wont change when selecting this particular Cam03. Selecting any other camera, say Cam01 or Cam02, as an active camera allows me to change the resolution.
Only when I select this particular camera am I unable to.*

Comment: hope you don't mind, i changed your question and answer a bit. You don't have to apologize - we all started Blender at one point. And of course the answer should be in the answer section - not in the question - so i deleted that part. Thanks for letting us know the answer! Have a great day!

Answer (score 3):

I found out that I have an addon that allows me to set a resolution as well, different resolutions for different cameras (the Photographer Add-On actually) it was locking the resolution for the camera. When I turned the resolution off from there it worked as expected :)